# Save checkbox in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I've updated my code. It's working except when i select more selectboxes at a time. If i select for example 2 selectboxes at the same time and i update them, the database updates them both to 0. When i update them separately, everything goes fine.

This the code right now:

```
<?php
include "header.php";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

    if(isset($_POST['aan']))
    {
        $doSave = implode(',',$_POST['aan']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE Modules SET 
            aan = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'
            WHERE module_name IN ('".mysql_real_escape_string($doSave)."')") or die (mysql_error());

        mysql_query("UPDATE Modules SET 
            aan = '".mysql_real_escape_string('0')."'
            WHERE module_name NOT IN ('".mysql_real_escape_string($doSave)."')") or die (mysql_error());

    }
    elseif(!isset($_POST['aan']))
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE Modules SET 
            aan = '".mysql_real_escape_string('0')."'
            WHERE module_name NOT IN ('".mysql_real_escape_string($doSave)."')") or die (mysql_error());
    }

    echo $doSave;

}

echo "<h1>Module beheer</h1>";

$getmodules = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Modules") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<form id='module' method='post'>";
   while($modules = mysql_fetch_array($getmodules))
   {
        echo "<label>".$modules['module_name']."</label>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='module_name' value='".$modules['module_name']."' />";
        if($modules['aan'] == 1) 
        { 
            $set_checked = "CHECKED";
        }
        else
        {
            $set_checked = "";
        }

        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='aan[]' value=".$modules['module_name']." ".$set_checked." /><br />";
    }
   echo "<input type='submit' id='modulesubmit' name='modulesubmit' value='Opslaan'>";

echo "</form>";

include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that `<label name='module_name'>` gets passed as part of the $_POST. You'll need to make it a `<input type="hidden">` in addition to the `<label>` tag (<label> is just for display purposes). In addition, you can't do that `while` loop in the form; you're going to end up with multiple checkboxes and module_names all with the same form input name, which won't work.

Comment: Also, you are using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. Take a look at your code; sometimes you are using `mysql_real_escape_string`, and sometimes you forget to. I HIGHLY suggest you switch to `mysqli_` or PDO - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: have it as follows now: `"<label><input type='hidden' name='module_name'>".$fetchmodules['module_name']."</label>"` but it doesn't makes any difference.

Comment: Tnx for the tip John. I will change that!

Answer (score 0):

Please start using PDO to access a database! The mysql_* functions are deprecated and not maintained anymore!

`status` is a preserved keyword in MySQL; using it as column name is not very smart. You can avoid it being used as keyword by using backtiks. But to avoid confusing I would take another column name. Let's say: `aan`.

Lets clean up your code a little bit.

You've got many lines which do the same 'logic'; whenever you write something multiple times in your code something is wrong. Why do you query the status seperately while the statu field itself is already in the module row?

Then same goes for the update statement? You just want to update the status field to 1|0.

```
if($_POST){
   if(intval($_POST['aan']) == 1 || intval($_POST['aan']) == 0){
     $aan = intval($_POST['aan']);
   }else{
     $aan = 0; //what if it's not 1|0
   }
   mysql_query("UPDATE Modules SET 
            aan = '".mysql_real_escape_string($aan)."'
            WHERE module_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['module_name'])."'") or die (mysql_error());

)

    echo "<h1>Module beheer</h1>";

    $getmodules = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Modules") or die(mysql_error());


    echo "<form id='module' method='post' action='*****add action parameter*****'>";
       while($m = mysql_fetch_array($getmodules)){
           {
           echo "<label name='module_name'>".$m['module_name']."</label>";
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='aan' value='".$m['aan']."'>";
           }

       echo "<input type='submit' id='modulesubmit' name='modulesubmit' value='Opslaan'>";

    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Tnx for your help stUrb. I've changed the table name and used your code, unfortunately with no result. I still have the same issue. It also doesn't gets the values out of the database, to fill in the checkboxes, anymore.

Comment: See my edit. I changed the `foreach` loop for a `while` statement.

Comment: I've changed it into a while statement before your edit but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: All right; try to start debugging the code. 1 - Instead of the mysql query within the $_POST-if: do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what variables get send to the page. 2 - build the sql-query first and echo it; look for some discrepanties; 3 - etc etc

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to **access label value** when submit your form,you cant access label value as you have define.
 You Have to change your code as :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Modules SET 
            Status = '".mysql_real_escape_string('1')."'
            WHERE module_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uitgeschakeld'])."'") or die (mysql_error());
            echo'bhal';
```

and  make change in following line-

```
**echo "<input type='checkbox' id='ingeschakeld' name='ingeschakeld' value='.$fetchmodules['module_name'].' checked></br>";**
```

Comment: The main issue here is the Use of `status` as a column name for the mysql table!!